# Customized html message in microsoft azure guest invitation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

This is the request body I am using to send email to the guests. However, I want to customize the customizedMessageBody using html tags and elements.

```
{ 
"invitedUserDisplayName": "Invited User", 
"invitedUserEmailAddress": "invited1234@yopmail.com", 
"invitedUserMessageInfo": {
    "messageLanguage": "string",
    "ccRecipients": [
         {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "xyz@yopmail.com",
                "address": "xyz@yopmail.com"
             }
         }
    ],
    "customizedMessageBody": "<html>hello tiger</html>"
 },
"sendInvitationMessage": true, 
"inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapps.microsoft.com"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As Message itself a text area. Due to the Security reason, **Customizing the customizedMessageBody using html tags and elements will not be processable**.

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/invitation-email-elements#invitation-message) details the available options you have for invitation messages